# jQuery event triggering, but on handler not reacting

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Have an odd issue with jQuery event handling, whereby my .triggers are firing, but .on handlers are not reacting.

Typically I would first guess the elements I want to react to the trigger are not completely set up yet, however before I fire the triggers I can check the element and see that the handlers are indeed present.

To facilitate some other functionality, I moved some code recently from having the handlers set directly on instances of an object, to instead trying several combinations of trying to set them in the prototype or in the constructor of the object that is being instantiated. This seems to be where the break has occurred, but I can't figure out why, seeing as the objects exist, the handlers exist, and only then do I attempt to trigger them. Essentially, the workflow should have changed, but the timing should still be the same.

Below example is setting in the constructor, didn't have much success extending the prototype and events either.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction, I'm sure it's not that complex.

https://codepen.io/othbert/pen/VEBEGw

```
<!-- html -->
<div data-obj="a"></div>
<div data-obj="b"></div>
```

and the javascript...

```
//js
globalObject = [];


function callEventTriggers(event){

    //for each element registered in the globalObject
    for (let index in globalObject) {

        let target = globalObject[index];

        //what event on what target
        console.log('triggering: ' + event + ' on target: ', target);

        //fire
        target.events.trigger(target, event);
    }
}

//objects to create
objectWithEvents = function(type){
    this.type = type;

    //using an empty jquery object to hold events
    this.events = $({});

    this.events.on('testevent', function(){

        //we never fire this 
        console.log('firing event', this);

        //just dump output to the container to demonstrate
        $('#content').html(this);
    });
}

//extend with prototype method to add object to a global
objectWithEvents.prototype.addToGlobalObject = function(global){

    global.push(this);
}

//for each object, create a js object instance
$('[data-obj]').each(function(){

    //create the instance
    var test = new objectWithEvents($(this).data('obj'));

    //attach it to document so we can show calling triggers from different function context.
    test.addToGlobalObject(globalObject);

});

//call the triggers from some unrelated code...
callEventTriggers('testevent');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the error in the code now.

```
//incorrect
target.events.trigger(target, event);
```

... should have the event as the first argument, not the target

```
//correct
target.events.trigger(event);
```